# How to manage pagination within cusom woocommerce loop

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Woocommerce has a custom class called [wc_get_products](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_get_products.html) to fetch products with some parameteres like product type, results per page etc ...

So i want to fetch bookable products type :

```
$args = array(
    'type' => 'booking',
    'numberposts'    => 2000, // yes i have 2000 products
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 12,
    'paged'          => 1
   );

   $bookings = wc_get_products( $args );
```

When getting products i have to make some conditions for each product (eg: if product is bookable for a specific date ), please see code below :

```
foreach(bookings as booking) 
{
    # ..... i omit some codes for shake of simplicity
    if ( $when >= $booking->from && $when <= $booking->to ) {
        // ... do not display this product
    }
}
```

Doing this if a product is not matching condition, he should not appear, but this will break my pagination because instead getting 12 products for page one i could get 8 if 4 are not matching.

Could you help me please? how to overcome this without affecting performance ?

Sorry for my bad english, and thank you.